On Putting Parentheses Around Item Numbers with Enumitem
Consider the code (which makes use of the enumerate package):
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}[ {(}1{)} ]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

and which produces

Now, the [ {(}1{)} ] trick does not work for enumitem.
QUESTION: How may I put parentheses around the item numbers in an enumerate environment when using enumitem (and not the enumerate package)?
Thank you.

The enumitem package has a syntax that's a wee bit different (and more powerful) syntax than the enumerate package. If you would like to have a short version for writing labels, than you need to load as
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

and then write your MWE as:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % <---

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document

Result:

For more possibilities for enumitem style settings please consult the package documentation.

A quick look into the package documentation (which nicely explains the many features of the package in details) shows that you should use the label key and \arabic* as placeholder for the digit.
So just add label={(\arabic*)} as option to your enumerate environment or set \setlist[enumerate]{label=(\arabic*)}:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



If you want to stick to the syntax you used with the enumerate package, you can call the enumitem package with the shortlabels option:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}[ {(}1{)} ]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

(There is actually no need for the curly braces around the parethesis in either package, so just \begin{enumerate}[(1)] also works.)
